# Proving a special case of the Intermediate Value Theorem using the Axiom of Completeness

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

Let $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Consider the special case where $f(a) < 0 < f(b)$. I want to show that $f(c) = 0$ for some $c \in (a,b)$. First let $$K=\{x \in [a,b]:f(x) \leq 0\}.$$

Since $K$ is bounded above by $b$ and $a \in K$, $K$ is nonempty. Therefore, by the Axiom of Completeness, $c = supK$ exists. There are three cases to consider: $f(c) > 0$, $f(c) < 0$, and $f(c) = 0$.

I have already went through proving that we can't have $f(c) > 0$. I just need help verifying if the following proof that we can't have $f(c) < 0$ is valid.

I'll be invoking the **Criterion for Discontinuity**: Let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and let $c \in A$ be a limit point of $A$. If there exists a sequence $(x_n) \subseteq A$ where $(x_n) \rightarrow x$ but $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(c)$, we may conclude that $f$ is not continuous at $c$.

**Proof**: Assume the case $f(c) < 0$. Then $c \in K$. Since $c$ is also $supK$, we have $c = maxK$ (not sure if $c = maxK$ is relevant).

Note that for all $x \in (c,b]$, $f(x) > 0$. Let $(x_n) \subseteq (c,b]$ with $(x_n) \rightarrow c$ be arbitrary.

Then $f(x_n) > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $f(x_n)$ cannot converge to a limit which is less than $0$ and so it does not converge to $f(c)$. We conclude (by the Criterion for Discontinuity) that $f$ is not continuous at $c$, which contradicts our original assumption that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and is continuous at $c$.

So, we can't have $f(c) <0$.

Comment: Your proof is correct.